# Anglar2 ngFor can not loop

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I have a 'nvi.json' file:

```
[
 {
"abbrev": "gn",
"book": "Gênesis",
"chapters": [
  {
    "1": {
      "1": "...",
      "2": "..."
    }
  },
  {
    "2": {
      "1": "...",
      "2": "..."
    }
  },
  {
    "3": {
      "1": "...",
      "2": "..."
    }
  }
 ]
 }
]
```

And I'm accessing like this:

```
export class BookPage {
public chapters: Array<string>;
private url: any = "../../assets/nvi.json";

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private NavParams: NavParams, public http: Http) {
let id = NavParams.get('id');

this.http.get(this.url).map(res => res.json())
  .subscribe(data => {
    this.chapters = data[id].chapters[0];
    console.log(this.chapters);
  });
  }
```

'this.chapters' contain the first chapter where it contains the verses.

But I can not loop these verses

```
<div *ngFor="let item of chapters">
 {{item}}
</div>
```

Console:

EXCEPTION: Error in ./BookPage class BookPage - inline template:33:5 caused by: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'.      NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: What do you want to iterate over? `*ngFor` can only iterate arrays. `chapters[0]` returns an object and this is why you get the error. If you remove `[0]` it might work.

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can't loop over an object with `*ngFor`. 
You have to reformat your json to have an array and not a literal object.

You can do something like that :

```
[
    {
        "abbrev": "gn",
        "book": "Gênesis",
        "chapters": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "verses": [
                    {
                        "id": "1",
                        "...": "...",
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "verses": [
                    {
                        "id": "1",
                        "...": "...",
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

the javascript

```
export class BookPage {
    public chapters:Array<string>;
    private url:any = "../../assets/nvi.json";

    constructor(public navCtrl:NavController, private NavParams:NavParams, public http:Http) {
        let id = NavParams.get('id');

        this.http.get(this.url).map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(data => {
            this.chapters = data[id].chapters; // remove the [0] or store directly the verses by accessing the verses property
            console.log(this.chapters);
        });
    }
}
```

the html

```
<div *ngFor="let chapter of chapters">
    {{chapter.id}}
    <div *ngFor="let verse of chapter.verses">
        {{verse.id}}
    </div>
</div>
```